# Chef recipie to start/stop deamontool services

Tags: chef-infra, svc

Im using chef to automate my production environment. One such production installation follows the process of

> - Installing a package from local repository
> - Restarting a service using svc deamontools ( eg svc -u *service_name*)

I know chef provides a resource called "package" to install a package from repository. But, is there a resource to restart/reload a deamontool service?

The below resource, would start/stop the services controlled by init.d. But I'm looking to control the services from svc deamontools. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

> service 'nginx' do
>    action [ :enable, :start ]
>   end

Answer (score 1):

### Preamble:

The service resource supports more than just init.d.

The `service` resource itself should guess which provider to use, if not you'll have to specify it with the provider attribute

Documentation is [here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html#providers).

### Answer

As far as I know there's no builtin provider for daemontools, so there's the [daemontools cookbook](https://github.com/jtimberman/daemontools) which could take care of all of this for you.

Another way to accomplish this is using the start, stop, status command attributes like this:

```
service "service_name" do
  support supports :status => true
  start_command "svc -u #{service_name}"
  stop_command "...."
  status_command "...."
  action :start
end
```

There's other attributes in the documentation of the service resource linked in preamble